# How to display a base64 image within a UIImageView?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uiimageview, uiimage

I got this Base64 gif image:

```
R0lGODlhDAAMALMBAP8AAP///wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAACH5BAUKAAEALAAAAAAMAAwAQAQZMMhJK7iY4p3nlZ8XgmNlnibXdVqolmhcRQA7
```

Now I want to display this Base64 String within my IPhone App.

I could get this working by using the WebView:

```
aUIWebView.scalesPageToFit = NO;
aUIWebView.opaque = NO;
aUIWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; 
[aUIWebView loadHTMLString:
  @"<html><body style=""background-color: transparent""><img src=""data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhDAAMALMBAP8AAP///wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAUKAAEALAAAAAAMAAwAQAQZMMhJK7iY4p3nlZ8XgmNlnibXdVqolmhcRQA7"" /></body></html>"
 baseURL:nil];
```

Is it possible to do the same thing by using the UIImageView?

Answer (score 132, accepted):

You don't have to encode it. Simply make a NSUrl, it knows the "data:"-url.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:base64String];    
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *ret = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

As mentioned in the comments, you have to make sure that you prepend your data with `data:image/png;base64,` or else your base64 data is useless.

Comment: Yeah! This is super-slick! Perhaps it's worth mentioning that you have to prepend the actual, raw base64 string with "data:image/png;base64," to get this to work. I deduced this from reading the WebView/HMLT code the OP posted, but I can see how some might have missed that nuance and then this wouldn't have worked.

Comment: Thanks ipmcc, I was disappointed that it wasn't working, until I read your comment.

Comment: Even if I prepended "data:image/png;base64," (without quotes) to my NSString I keep getting a nil imageData. Could someone bring some light? @ipmcc: what do you mean with "raw" string? Are you meaning the underlying char *?

Comment: No, I just mean that if the string didn't start with `data:image/png;base64,` it would need to be prepended. NSString is the type required by `-URLWithString:`. If you're not having luck, you should double-check your Base64 data.

Comment: @ipmcc you're right, my base64 data was slightly exceeding the 2048 bytes url size limit. Thanks.

Comment: Weird, in all my experiments the NSURL always came out as nil.

Comment: NSURL always come out as nil for me as well until I realized that the server fed me a Base64 string with a bunch of newlines (\n). When I stripped them off, it worked.

Answer (score 70):

Very old question, but as of iOS7 there is a new, much easier way to do so, hence I'm writing it here so future readers can use this.

```
NSData* data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:base64String options:0];
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

Very easy to use, and will not hit the 2048 byte size limit of a URL.

Comment: Thanks. Here's the UIImage extension I made in Swift based on your answer.

 extension UIImage {
  class func fromBase64(base64: String) -> UIImage? {
   //Remove prefix if present
   let PREFIX = "data:image/png;base64,"
   let dataOnly: String
   if base64.startsWith(PREFIX) {
    dataOnly = base64.substringFromIndex(base64.startIndex.advancedBy(PREFIX.length))
   } else {
    dataOnly = base64
   }
   
   if let data = NSData(base64EncodedString: dataOnly, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.init(rawValue: 0)) {
    return UIImage(data: data)
   }
   return nil
  }
 }

Comment: nice and clean ditto , plus one for the reasonable expectation of blowing the size limit on url.

Answer (score 16):

This Code will display an base64 encoded string as a picture:

```
NSString *str = @"data:image/jpg;base64,";
str = [str stringByAppendingString:restauInfo.picture];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]];
```

restauInfo.picture is an NSString which contains the base64 encoded JPG

In my case the Value from "restauInfo.picture" comes from a database

Comment: I figured this out by the post from masche and the comment from ipmcc. So I decided to write a new answer with code that can just be copied - hope this helps.

Answer (score 8):

You can do something like the following:

```
(UIImage *)decodeBase64ToImage:(NSString *)strEncodeData {
  NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithBase64EncodedString:strEncodeData options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];
  return [UIImage imageWithData:data];
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
UIImage *image = [self decodeBase64ToImage:dataString];
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Decode Base64 to raw binary. You're on your own here. You might find `cStringUsingEncoding:` of `NSString` useful.
2. Create `NSData` instance using `dataWithBytes:length:`
3. Use `[UIImage imageWithData:]` to load it.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks porneL

I could find a Base64 script using google:
[Base64.m](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/5752-have-problem-base64-endcoder-decoder.html)

So I modified it a little bit and could get a working test code:

```
NSString * base64img = @"R0lGODlhDAAMALMBAP8AAP///wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAUKAAEALAAAAAAMAAwAQAQZMMhJK7iY4p3nlZ8XgmNlnibXdVqolmhcRQA7";
base64Data = [base64img dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
base64Bytes = [base64Data bytes];
mutableData = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:[base64Data length]];
lentext = [base64Data length];

while( YES ) {
       if( ixtext >= lentext ) break;
       ch = base64Bytes[ixtext++];
       flignore = NO;

       if( ( ch >= 'A' ) && ( ch <= 'Z' ) ) ch = ch - 'A';
       else if( ( ch >= 'a' ) && ( ch <= 'z' ) ) ch = ch - 'a' + 26;
       else if( ( ch >= '0' ) && ( ch <= '9' ) ) ch = ch - '0' + 52;
    else if( ch == '+' ) ch = 62;
       else if( ch == '=' ) flendtext = YES;
       else if( ch == '/' ) ch = 63;
       else flignore = YES;

       if( ! flignore ) {
        short ctcharsinbuf = 3;
        BOOL flbreak = NO;

        if( flendtext ) {
            if( ! ixinbuf ) break;
            if( ( ixinbuf == 1 ) || ( ixinbuf == 2 ) ) ctcharsinbuf = 1;
            else ctcharsinbuf = 2;
            ixinbuf = 3;
            flbreak = YES;
        }

        inbuf [ixinbuf++] = ch;

        if( ixinbuf == 4 ) {
            ixinbuf = 0;
            outbuf [0] = ( inbuf[0] << 2 ) | ( ( inbuf[1] & 0x30) >> 4 );
            outbuf [1] = ( ( inbuf[1] & 0x0F ) << 4 ) | ( ( inbuf[2] & 0x3C ) >> 2 );
            outbuf [2] = ( ( inbuf[2] & 0x03 ) << 6 ) | ( inbuf[3] & 0x3F );

            for( i = 0; i < ctcharsinbuf; i++ )
                [mutableData appendBytes:&outbuf[i] length:1];
        }

        if( flbreak )  break;
       }
}


//Finally I can access my image data:
aUIImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithData:mutableData]];
```

Answer (score 2):

### Objective-C

```
NSString *plainString = @"foo";
```

Encoding

```
NSData *plainData = [plainString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *base64String = [plainData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
NSLog(@"%@", base64String);
```

Decoding

```
NSData *decodedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:base64String options:0];
NSString *decodedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decodedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", decodedString);
```

Option

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:
  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"data:application/octet-stream;base64,%@",
       base64String]];

 return [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL];
```

### Swift

```
let plainString = "foo"
```

Encoding

```
let plainData = (plainString as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let base64String = plainData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.fromRaw(0)!)
println(base64String)
```

Decoding

```
let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64String, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.fromRaw(0)!)
let decodedString = NSString(data: decodedData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)    
println(decodedString) // foo
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4+**

```
let base64EncodedString = "" // Your Base64 Encoded String
if let imageData = Data(base64Encoded: base64EncodedString) {
                let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
                self.imageView.image = image
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone is looking for the *Swift* code to accomplish this (based on the *Objective-C* answer provided by Jonathan M), here it is:

```
var data = NSData (base64EncodedString: base64String, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(0))
var image = UIImage(data: data!)
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case worked a solution proposed here by @Masche. As I needed it in **Swift 2.0** so:

```
let url = NSURL(string: imageString)
let data = NSData.init(contentsOfURL: url!)
let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
```

Answer (score 0):

Code snippet for downloading a text file with base64 image string inside, then saving/reading the file and finally creating an image to display right in the view

[In Case You Need To Decode Image To Base64 Click Here](https://www.base64-image.de/)

```
NSString *downloadUrl = "http://www.server.com/file.txt";
//
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: downloadUrl]];
//
// DOWNLOAD THE FILE
//
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]
completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
{
    if (error) {

        NSLog(@"Download Error:%@",error.description);

    }
    if (data) {
        [data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
        //
        // PROCESS BASE 64 STRING
        //
        NSString * fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
        //
        // PROCESS BASE 64 STRING
        //
        NSString *base64String = fileContents;
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:base64String];
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        //
        // CREATE IMAGE
        //
        UIImage *ret = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        self.myImage.image = ret;
    }
}
```