# Get string from http://xxxx.com/xx.bin file to create a UIImage on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, binary, uiimage, nsdata

I have images encoded as base64 stored on my server as .bins. I want to get the string contained in the .bin to create UIImages as explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1378707/385559).

How do I get the string from the url of the bin programmatically via the iPhone?

Comment: So you basically need to get certain characters out of a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [ASIHTTP](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) wich is a wrapper around NSURLConnection and CFNetwork API, and then you could do something like this:

```
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xxxx.com/xx.bin"];
  ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
  [request startSynchronous];
  NSError *error = [request error];
  if (!error) {
    NSString *response = [request responseString];
  }
```

This is a synchronous call, you can also use ASI to do the call asynchronous with delegates, blocks, queues, etc.

Comment: Are you %100 sure this will work? When I place `http://xxx.com/xx.bin` in a browser it downloads the .bin as a file. Would your code actually return a string?

Comment: If that .bin contains a string inside it should work, why you don't tested, or post the file

Comment: Actually I've just realized it's a valid image file. Sorry. but you get the accept and vote for effort. Thanks again.

Comment: Great that you can sort that out!