# How can I take an encoded image from a JSON query and encode it as a UIImage in objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, image, converters

So I grab a base64 encoded data object out of a JSON request (data{phto => base64stuff})

```
NSData *imagedata = [data objectForKey:@"phto"];
```

Then I try to convert it using:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: [imagedata bytes]];
```

And this results in this error:

```
-[__NSCFString bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I've printed out the image data, and it is correct.  Is there some other formatting I need to do or something?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1378707/308315

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the `photo` key is a base64 encoded string, not data. You need something like this:

```
NSString *base64String = data[@"photo"];
NSData *imageData = ... // Some call to convert the base64 encoding string to NSData
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

For some strange reason there is no base64 encoder/decoder supplied with the iOS SDK. You need to use one of the many 3rd party libraries or write your own. Some quick searching will point you in the right direction.