# Converting from JSON string to UIImage always gives null?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, uiimage

I Get this kind of JSON:

**NOTE:** I put dots in "content" because it is too long byte array abd just to explain the situation.

```
{
   "id":"53abc6a7975a9c10c292f670",
   "nfcId":"testse",
   "company":"TESt",
   "qrId":"testvalue",
   "address":"ajs;ldfh",
   "mimeType":"IMAGE",
   "url":"",
   "content":"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAA....."
}
```

And im trying to get this Json and diplay this information
the "content" field has a Byte array converted on the server from Image to byte array.

I use this code in xCode to convert those bytes to NSData, then to UIImage to be able to display it in UIImageView:

```
    NSData *dataImage = [jsonArray[key] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"data = %@", dataImage);
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:dataImage];
    NSLog(@"img = %@", img);
```

The image is always gives me null.Although, data give me array of data.

I tried all kinds of encodings as a NSData parameters also:

```
dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding
dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF32StringEncoding
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display a base64 image within a UIImageView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366837/how-to-display-a-base64-image-within-a-uiimageview)

Comment: Your `content` would appear to be a base-64 string representation of the image data.

Comment: it is .png image @ali59a

Comment: It's base64 encoded. Take a look at the question I linked to.

Comment: @jurgemaister thank you so much, I looked at the title and i tried the code i posted below.

Comment: By the way, image data won't ever be encoded by any string encoding you have tried. You can't encode image data using `UTF8`, `UTF16` or `ASCII`. They are _String_ encodings, not image encodings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this code just right now and it works:

```
NSData* dataImage = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:jsonArray[key] options:0];
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:dataImage];
```

The "content" encoded by Base64 String type.

Answer (score 2):

I've used code like this before

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"data:image/png;base64,%@",jsonArray[key]]];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

Note that `initWithBase64EncodedString` is only available from iOS7 onwards

Comment: But i dont always know if it is PNG or JPG. can i make it deal with all images ?

Comment: yes, it does not matter what ever the image file extension is. But before converting data to image do check if(imageData) then convert else add some dummy image depending on your requirement. If we don't check if(imageData) when there is no data app will crash because of convert null to image