# Applying Base64 String to UIImageView not working in iOS Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, swift2, base64

I have a Base64 string saved from Swift into mysql db. When it comes back, it does not display an image.

How it looks in the db:

LzlqLzRBQVFTa1pKUmdBQkFRQUFTQUJJQUFELzRRQk1SWGhwWmdBQVRVMEFLZ0FBQUFnQUFnRVNBQU1BQUFBQg0KQUFFQUFJZHBBQVFBQUFBQkFBQUFKZ0FBQUFBQUFxQUNBQEZMUlUlJSUUFVVVVVQUZGRkZBQlJSUlFBVVVVVUFGRkZGQUJSUlJRQVVVVVVBRkZGRkFCUlJSUUFVVQ0KVVVBRkZGaWdBcEtXaWdBcEtXaw0Kb0FLS0tLQUNpaWlnQW9vb29BS0tLS0FDaWlpZ0Fvb29vQVNpbG9vQVNpbG9vQVNpaWlnQW9vb29BS0tLS0FDaQ0KaWlnQW9vb29BS0tLS0FDaWlpZ0Fvb29vQUtLS0tB

and this is how I am attempting to receive it but its not working:

```
let partUrl = "data:image/jpg;base64,";
let appndd = partUrl.stringByAppendingString(baseStringNew!)

let urlWeb = appndd
let requestURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlWeb)!
let urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: requestURL)
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest) {
   (data, response, error) -> Void in

   if error == nil {
      NSLog("Success!")

      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

      imageNewView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
      imageNewView.clipsToBounds = true

      // Adding a border to the image profile
      imageNewView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
      imageNewView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor
      imageNewView.image = UIImage(data:data!)

      })

  } else {
      NSLog("Fail")
  }

 } //end of task

 task.resume()
```

This displays a blank image in the UIImageView. How do I get this string to show up as an image?

Comment: plugged your string in to http://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter, didnt show up as an image. are you sure its actually an image? Where did it come from?

Comment: its an image i removed some of the url to make it fit in the StackOverflow window

Comment: Have you tried the base64 encoded string initializer for NSData `NSData(base64EncodedString:string, options:[])`, and then using that NSData to create the UIImage?

Comment: tried this and its still not working... im noticing the dataurl doesn't have the "=" at the end when it hits the database. Wondering if this is the cause.

Comment: Are you sanitizing it when you put it into the database and not when you take it out? = is a used for queries in mysql so it could be being sanitized.

Comment: no im not... im storing it directly from my app into mysql using: base64String2 = base64String2.toBase64() and when i print it, it looks fine!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you prepend your data with `data:image/png;base64`.

Here is an q&a about this, [How to display a base64 image within a UIImageView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366837/how-to-display-a-base64-image-within-a-uiimageview)

Comment: this fails: let partUrl = "data:image/png;base64,";
                        let appndd = partUrl.stringByAppendingString(baseStringNew!)
                        
                        let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: appndd, options:[])
                        imageNewView.image = UIImage(data:decodedData!)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the base64 string you stored and retrieved from your MySQL DB. Try using BLOB data type.

Then converting base64 string to NSData then UIImage is pretty easy and straightforward.

```
let rawData = NSData.init(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.png")!)!
let base64String = rawData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
let imageData = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64String, options: .IgnoreUnknownCharacters)
let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
```

Comment: this fails at the let rawData = NSData... i switched my datatype to blob but still no luck. My string looks like let:  partUrl = "data:image/jpg;base64,";
                        let appndd = partUrl.stringByAppendingString(baseStringNew!)

Comment: i guess my confusion is on how do i contruct the string... right now my base64 pulls in like:  LzlqLzRBQVFTa1 i appended it with the: data:image/jpg;base64, but doesnt seem to like this inside of your suggested NSURL(string: appndd)

Comment: No need to append "image/jpg;base64". Also, are you storing the URL (converted to base64 string) of the image into your DB?